# Android I get Your Xcode is outdated error on installing ADB

Tags: android, xcode, macos, adb

when i want to install `android-platform-tools` i get error:

```
Ebtekars-MacBook-Pro:Android mahdi$ brew install android-platform-tools
Error: Your Xcode (8.0) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

My xcode version on App Store is 8.1 and its updated to last version but i get error. how can i resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: i see you're using Homebrew, have you tried installing platform tools using the SDK Manager?

Comment: do not use `homebrew` for the `platform-tools` - use the official package provided by Google